# Getting to the correct ul

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have to add new element when the + button is clicked and the element should go to the unordered list from that `div`. Every time when i click the the `+` button the element goes to the last `div` i have created.I know my mistake is that `ul` in my `javascript` is an array of uls but do not know how to fix it.I think i have to use `this` key word but dont get it how. Can someone more experienced give me some advice?

```js
let check = (function(){
   
    function isActive (elem) {
        if(elem.checked == true){
            elem.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'forestGreen';
        }else{
            elem.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        }
    }
   
    return {
        isActive: isActive
    }
   
})();
   
 
let section = (function(){ 
 
    function Section(){
        //create section div
        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'wrapper');
        let wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');
        let len = wrapper.length-1;
        wrapper[len].parentNode.appendChild(newDiv);
       
        //create div for list items
        let innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        innerDiv.setAttribute('id', 'business');
        newDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
       
        //create title
        let title = document.createElement('h3');
        let txtTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
        let createTitle = document.createTextNode(txtTitle);
        title.appendChild(createTitle);
        title.setAttribute('tag','h3');
        innerDiv.appendChild(title);
       
        //create new Unordered List
        let newUl = document.createElement('ul');
        newUl.setAttribute('tag', 'ul');
        innerDiv.appendChild(newUl);
       
        //create add button
        let btn = document.createElement('input');
        btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        btn.setAttribute('value', '+');
        btn.setAttribute('class', 'rightInputs');
        newDiv.appendChild(btn);
        btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'section.createElement()');
       
        //create field for the elements
        let txtField = document.createElement('input');
        txtField.setAttribute('value', 'Add item...');
        txtField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        txtField.setAttribute('class', 'rightInputs');
        txtField.setAttribute('onMouseOver', 'clearContent(this)');
        newDiv.appendChild(txtField);
    }
 
    function createElement(){
        //create LI
        let elem = document.createElement('li');
        let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('rightInputs');
        let lastInp = inputs[inputs.length-1].value;
        let txtLi = document.createTextNode(lastInp);
        let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
        //create checkbox
        let chBox = document.createElement('input');
        chBox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        chBox.setAttribute('onclick', 'check.isActive(this)');
        //------------
        elem.setAttribute('tag', 'li');
        elem.appendChild(chBox);
        elem.appendChild(txtLi);
        ul[ul.length-1].appendChild(elem);
    }
 
    function addToDOM(){
        return new Section();
    }
   
    return {
        addToDOM: addToDOM,
        createElement: createElement
    }
   
})();
 
function clearContent(elem){
    if(elem.value == 'Add item...' || elem.value == 'Title..'){
        elem.value = '';
    }
}
```

```css
#mainDiv {
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
}
 
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
 
#title{
    width: 150px;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
 
#addSection {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
 
#container {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    border: 5px double gray;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
 
#shoppingList {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 375px;
    height: 165px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
 
#business {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 375px;
    height: 165px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
 
ul {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    list-style: none;
}
 
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}
 
input {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 
.rightInputs {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
 
h3 {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
 
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='mainDiv'>
        <h1> Tuesday <em>TODO</em> List </h1>
        <div id='container'>
                <div class='wrapper'>  
                    <div id='shoppingList'>
                        <h3> Shopping List </h3>
                        <ul id='forShopping'>
                            <li><input type='checkbox' onclick='check.isActive(this)'> Air-freshener</input></li>
                            <li><input type='checkbox' onclick='check.isActive(this)'> Pampers</input></li>
                            <li><input type='checkbox' onclick='check.isActive(this)'> Newspapper</input></li>
                            <li><input type='checkbox' onclick='check.isActive(this)'> Toilet paper</input></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <input class='rightInputs' type='button' value='+' onclick='section.createElement()'/>
                    <input class='rightInputs' type='text' value='Add item...'
                            onMouseOver='clearContent(this)'/>
                </div>
                <div class='wrapper'>
                    <div id='business'>
                        <h3> Business List </h3>
                        <ul id='forBusiness'>
                            <li><input type='checkbox' onclick='check.isActive(this)'> Inspect fiscal year report</input></li>
                            <li><input type='checkbox' onclick='check.isActive(this)'> Lunch with board of directors</input></li>
                            <li><input type='checkbox' onclick='check.isActive(this)'> Fire Jackson</input></li>
                            <li><input type='checkbox' onclick='check.isActive(this)'> Take a nap</input></li>
                            <li><input type='checkbox' onclick='check.isActive(this)'> Arrange meeting with investors</input></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <input class='rightInputs' type='button' value='+' onclick='section.createElement()'/>
                    <input class='rightInputs' type='text' value='Add item...'
                            onMouseOver='clearContent(this)'/>
                </div>
        </div>
        <input id='title' type='text' value='Title..' onMouseOver='clearContent(this)'/>
        <input id='addSection' type='button' value='New Section' onclick='section.addToDOM()'/>
    </div>
```

[HTML code](http://pastebin.com/6KybFxaM)

[JavaScript code](http://pastebin.com/4pArc2kV)

[CSS code](http://pastebin.com/R5U2PieG)

Comment: please provide code in your question, not externally.

Comment: I`m thankful for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the html code of your `+` button like this

```
<input class='rightInputs' type='button' value='+' data-index="0" onclick='section.createElement(event)'/>
```

Using the `data-index` you will set the index of the list you want to change, and you pass the `event` object to the function `createElement`. Than update your `createElement` function like this:

```
function createElement(e) {
  //..
  ul[e.target.dataset.index].appendChild(elem);
}
```

You will use the property `data-index` from the button to target the right list.

Also update your `Section` function which creates new sections, and set the `data-index` attribute to the new button:

```
btn.setAttribute('data-index', document.getElementsByTagName('ul').length - 1);
```

and also update the `click` attribute:

```
btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'section.createElement(event)');
```

Here is working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dm06a7db/

Comment: Your welcome, please, do not forget to mark the right answer in order to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this to find the all the UL in the page :

```
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
```

Then you take the last one `( ul[ul.length-1].appendChild(elem);)`
 you need to find the UL based on the button that was clicked.

The way would do this is give every UL a unique id or class and pass that to the `createElement()` function, that find the UL base on that id or class

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all `<ul>` when you should be looking for a specific one.

The best way to get a specific one is to give it a label and reference it explicitly.

Change the call to:

```
<!-- Important, use double quotes for the onclick call -->
<input class='rightInputs' type='button' value='+' onclick="section.createElement('forShopping')"/>
```

And then you can update your javascript.

```
function createElement(selector){
    //create LI
    let elem = document.createElement('li');
    let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('rightInputs');
    let lastInp = inputs[inputs.length-1].value;
    let txtLi = document.createTextNode(lastInp);
    //create checkbox
    let chBox = document.createElement('input');
    chBox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
    chBox.setAttribute('onclick', 'check.isActive(this)');
    //------------
    elem.setAttribute('tag', 'li');
    elem.appendChild(chBox);
    elem.appendChild(txtLi);

    document.getElementById(selector).appendChild(elem);
}
```

It's also worth noting that using things like `onclick=""` have problems. It's better to give it an ID and attach an event handler in the Javascript.

```
// html
<input class="rightInputs" id="addToShopping" type="button" value='+' />

// in the javascript
document.getElementById('addToShopping').addEventListener('click', function() {
    section.createElement('forShopping');
});
```